# initializing array in function

Tags: c#, arrays, function

hi i have code like this

```
int[] n1 = new int[] {2, 4, 6, 8};
char[] n2 = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' };
```

i want to pass that 2 variabel to function
like this

```
 public static void myTest(int[] n1, char[] n2) 
 {
  .........
 }
```

the problem is i can't initializing array in function with this code

```
 n1 = {2, 4, 6, 8};
 n2 = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' };
 //or with this one
 n1[] = {2, 4, 6, 8};
 n2[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' };
```

where i'm missing?
or how to do it correctly?

Comment: This makes no sense. You want to pass already initialized arrays into a function.. but you're saying you can't initialize them in the function? Not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Have you tried `n1 = new[] { ... };`? But even so, as @Simon says, this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Passing them as a parameter is useless because they will be overwritten in the method body. Unless you're really using n1 and n2 before your new initialization.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead sory if my question not clear, i mean in parrent i just want to declare array, and then initializing it in function....not initializing in both parent and function

Comment: You need to pass it as `ref`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `ref` keyword here, but rather the `out` keyword. Why is this?

When using `ref` you will need to initialize the values before passing them into the method - e.g. like this:

```
var arrayInt = new int[0];
var arrayChar = new char[0];

MyTest(ref arrayInt, ref arrayChar);
```

with `MyTest` defined as `MyTest(ref int[] n1, ref char[] n2)  { ... }`.

When using the `out` keyword instead you can pass unitialized values into the method:

```
int[] arrayInt;
char[] arrayChar;

MyTest(out arrayInt, out arrayChar);
```

with `MyTest` defined as follows:

```
public static void MyTest(out int[] n1, out char[] n2) 
{
    n1 = new[] {2, 4, 6, 8};
    n2 = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use array initialization syntax when array is being created.

You could create new one, with new content instead:

```
n1 = new[] {2, 4, 6, 8};
n2 = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' };
```

**Update**

but, **it will not update the variables you passed to method as parameters**. To make that happen you have to pass them by ref, using `ref` keyword:

```
public static void myTest(ref int[] n1, ref char[] n2) 
{
    n1 = new[] {2, 4, 6, 8};
    n2 = new [] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' };
}
```

Comment: Works, but probably useless. The array in the calling method is not going to get assigned to, unless you use the `ref` keyword.

Comment: @mrlucmorin yeah...after i try in my project it's actually useless, so i try different way

Comment: @katik if I may, I would invite you to consider very seriously the comments that others make on your question instead of jumping on what may seem to be the right answer, which was obviously wrong in this case.

Comment: @mrlucmorin hm...agreed so what i must do? remove correct answer in this solution or ...?

Comment: @katik You can do that if you think my answer does not match your question. I'm totally OK with that. But, I would advice you to ask more clear questions next time, to make sure you get an answer you're looking for.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yeah, i guess my question really confused after all..i will try make cleared question next time

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I honestly you should know better than to give this kind of answer knowing the implications and seeing that the OP has little clue about what he's doing